# Images dont show up on an iPhone

Tags: images, iphone

When visiting the url http://symbius.nl/juridisch/ on an iPhone or iPad the images inside the page dont show..

I have disabled all plugins (except for visual composer) but the problem seems to stay.

Any thoughts?

EDIT: iPhone Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wxdsz3i8hpvmwpo/Foto%2019-08-14%2013%2056%2056.png

Comment: Strange. Don't have an iPhone, but the image is shown on an Android mobile.

Comment: I checked in iPhone emulator and image is shown.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem to be the size of the images.

The iphone has a maximum size for images.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324646/background-image-does-not-show-on-iphone-ipad